How to select the right overload of function template?
I'm using libcxx 16.0.0 from the LLVM project.
In __algorithm/fill_n.h, there is the following function:
// fill_n isn't specialized for std::memset, because the compiler already optimizes the loop to a call to std::memset.

template <class _OutputIterator, class _Size, class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_SINCE_CXX20
_OutputIterator
__fill_n(_OutputIterator __first, _Size __n, const _Tp& __value)
{
    for (; __n > 0; ++__first, (void) --__n)
        *__first = __value;
    return __first;
}

The problem is that in my case the function is not optimized to std::memset. So I would like to do this specialization manually.
I was hoping to add an overload of __fil_n for trivially copyable _Tp and contiguous iterators (including std::array's iterator).
So, given the following code,
template <typename T, int N> struct foo_t {
  struct iterator {};
};

template <typename T> int f(T) { return 1; }

template <typename T, int N> int f(typename foo_t<T, N>::iterator) { return 2; }

int main() {
  foo_t<int, 10>::iterator a;

  return f(a);
}

How can I change the signatures of f so that the second overload is selected at the f function call in main ?
A solution with a C++ version >= 11 but <20 would be ideal.

At the moment it cannot possibly choose the second overload because you have not specified N.  If you donʼt want to call f<N>(a) for some N, what do you even want selecting the second overload to do?

I believe you can't make a deduction from a type to the surrounding type. Consider e.g. a struct containing a typedef referencing the iterator struct from a completely unrelated foo_t.

typename foo_t<T, N>::iterator is a non deduced context. This is a xy problem. What you ask for directly is not possible, but we can help you find other ways if you tell us about the actual problem rather than only about what you think would make a solution. Why do you need those two overloads?

suppose foo_t had using iterator = int; instead of the nested struct, then any foo_t<T, N>::iterator would be the same type. This is generally not excluded or forbidden, hence there is no way to deduce T and N given only the type of the iterator

Well, every question is a XY problem, isn't it ? :) The main issue here is that std::__fil_n from libcxx 16.0.0 is supposed to be optimized as a memset, but is is not in my case. So I would like to add an overload for std::array::iterator and trivially copyable types to rewrite it with memset.

No not every quesiton is a xy problem. We call it a xy problem when the quesiton you did ask has no answer but there are good chances that the quesiton you did not ask has one. What you ask for cannot be done. You cannot decude T or N from typename foo_t<T, N>::iterator. Please add the information about std::array::iterator in the question.

I suppose what you actually want is a specialziation for any T for which std::is_trivially_copyable< iterator_traits<T>::value_type> is true.

And, if I understand correctly, the iterator should be a ContiguousIterator. But the ContiguousIterator traits are not available in C++ < 20 :(

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: "What you ask for directly is not possible" I changed f to be callable from main as wanted. But it would not be possible for std::array<T, N>.

@Dorian XY-problem is a slang for situation where one asks to do odd or weird Y in (false) belief that Y is required or commonly used to achieve some X they fail to mention. It's a form of what is known in logic as modal fallacy, often in mix with a masked-man fallacy, non-sequitur , etc.

with typename foo_t<T, N>::iterator, T and N are non deducible.
friend function helps:
template <typename T, int N>
struct foo_t {
  struct iterator {
      friend int f(iterator) { return 2; } // f is no longer template
  };
};

template <typename T> int f(T) { return 1; }

Demo

If I understand correctly, overload resolution considers non-template function before template ones, and ADL allows to see the nested f function? In any case, this solves the problem, very smart.

f isn't nested, it is declared in the outer scope.

You cannot portably add a specialization of std::fill_n. Generally you are not allowed to add to namespace std (unless it is explicitly stated otherwise, for example std::hash).
However, you do not have to. Read the comment in the code:

// fill_n isn't specialized for std::memset, because the compiler already optimizes the loop to a call to std::memset


You do not have to manually add a specialization. The implementation does not provide one, because it knows that when the type is trivially copyable the loop in the existing specialization will be optimized to use std::memset.

Another reason you do not have to add a specialization or the overload to std is ADL. For that I refer you to this answer.

To your question about choosing the overload...
Here:
template <typename T, int N> int f(typename foo_t<T, N>::iterator) { return 2;}

foo_t<T,N>::iterator is a non deduced context. You cannot infer the type of container from the type of iterator. For example std::vector<int>::iterator can be implemented as plain int*. However, the same is true for std::array<N,int>::iterator. Or more specifically, there is no reason to expect std::array<N,int>::iterator to be different for different N.

If you want to write a function that does something special for iterators to trivially copyable types you can use std::is_trivially_copyable to write a concept
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
concept refers_to_trivially_copyable = std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::decay_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>>;

template <typename T> requires (!refers_to_trivially_copyable<T>)
void foo(const T&) { std::cout << "genereal overload\n"; }

template <refers_to_trivially_copyable T>
void foo(const T&) { std::cout << "trivially copybale\n";}


int main() {
    int* x = nullptr;
    foo(x);
    foo(&std::cout);
}

Output:
trivially copybale
genereal overload

Forgive me the verbose unreadable concept. I suppose it could be written much shorter, it just checks if dereferencing an instance of type T yields a type that can be copied via std::memcpy or std::memset.

Thanks for the detailed answer. I ship the STL, so I'm fine with adding specialization. Unfortunately the code is not compiled but interpreted, so the memset optimization won't kick in and that's why I have to do it manually (there is a memset builtin in the interpreter)

@Dorian ok, I expected something along the line of that as you accepted the other answer. I thought I would be worthwhile to mention the stuff also considering that not all future readers are implementers of the stl ;)
